# Current date in data explorer - DATE() does not work

Tags: support, data-explorer, statistics

I'm trying to determine *age* of post and make a graph based upon it:

[image: Stats per time]

I made this query:

```
select sum(ViewCount), DATE() - CreationDate AS age
    FROM Posts
    WHERE
        PostTypeId = 1
    GROUP BY age
    ORDER BY age
```

I'm using `DATE()` but that doesn't work:

[image: 'DATE' is not a recognized built-in function name.]

How should I calculate post age?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since Data Explorer exposes data stored in SQL Server, use T-SQL's [`DATEDIFF()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) function. [For example](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/255912), grouping by age in days*:

```sql
SELECT SUM(ViewCount), DATEDIFF(day, CreationDate, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AS age
  FROM Posts
 WHERE PostTypeId = 1
 GROUP BY DATEDIFF(day, CreationDate, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
 ORDER BY age
```

<sub>* Keeping in mind that for subsequent runs the values [may be skewed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/139129/150235) due [to caching](http://shouldiblamecaching.com), though this has no impact on the results other than shifting the time points</sub>